# How to sync activerecord clock with mysql server clock instead of the server clock hosting the app?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, time

Like many of you, we have many (equivalent) servers in production to handle large traffic. For a reason i dont need to explain, our servers are completely closed for the outside world, even for access on ntp ports in order to sync time.

So i need to hack the rails app to get time not from the server hosting it, but from the one hosting our common database, so that timestamps (created_at / updated_at) can stand logic.

Any idea how to do that ?

Comment: Sounds like you are in for a world of pain. If you can't get an outside sync to a reliable clock source, at least set up an internal NTP server with *some* time so that all your servers have the same (potentially skewed) time.

Comment: Or invest a couple of bugs in a GPS time receiver to get the actual and reliable time.

Comment: Holger Just: This is the right solution that we want to do, but for another reason we just cant do it now. Actually, when we reboot a server, it gets the good time. But after 2 weeks, it starts to deviate seriously...

Comment: So we try to fix it with the software way meantime

Comment: This is something you have to fix on the OS level in order to ensure reliable operation. I mean, you could somehow patch `Time.now` to get another time but it will probably break with any C extensions and all components outside of Rails (including OpenSSL). You would make things much more complicated since you now have two different time sources on your server.

Comment: For the GPS time receiver, no way. We are using aws cloud. When a server starts, it uses their synced time. That's why it is "approximatively" working until now...

Comment: With activerecord, it is possible to override created_at timestamp. So the solution i thought about is, instead of using Time.now (from the server) when inserting an object, use the mysql current date...

Comment: What do you think about it ?

Comment: your mysql servers are not closed from the outer world, then?

Comment: we have a single mysql server which is closed from the outer world too, but if all our app servers are synced with it's own clock, it fixes the problem. (if it has 4 seconds of time lag, it's ok because every insert will have the same lag and it doesnt affect the order)